# WPF Drawing a list of rectangles in a collection

Tags: wpf, xaml, canvas, datatemplate, itemscontrol

My WPF app has a ViewModel that has an ObservableCollection that holds objects of type `Item`.  Each Item has a color and a Rect that is drawn on the canvas:

Item Class:

```
public class Item
{
    public Color ItemColor {get; set;}
    public Rect ScaledRectangle {get; set;}
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="Items" ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:ItemView  Visibility="Visible">
                    <local:ItemView.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ItemColor}"/>
                        </local:ItemView.Background>
                    </local:ItemView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding ScaledRectangle.Left}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding ScaledRectangle.Top}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Width" Value="{Binding ScaledRectangle.Width}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Height" Value="{Binding ScaledRectangle.Height}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

In my ViewModel, all I have to do is add a new Item to the ObservableCollection to draw it on the screen.

This works really well but now I find I need to change the ScaledRectangle property to some kind of collection.  I want to modify this XAML to draw each rectangle in the ScaledRectangles collection.  Can I modify this XAML so I can keep the ViewModel functionality to something like `viewModel.AddNewItem(newItem)`?

Comment: Just a note, Mode=TwoWay on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless.

Comment: Instead of a Rect, you may use a Geometry that is visualized by a Path element in the ItemTemplate. The Geometry could be a GeometryGroup with child Geometries, e.g. RectangleGeometries.

Comment: So you want that Item has a collection of Rect objects? And you still have a collection of Item? And you want to show all in the same ItemsControl?

Comment: Why is it you want a collection of rect in your Item?  The purpose of a viewmodel is to adapt data to the view. If you want to deal with a collection which has a collection of rectangles for data processing purposes than why not just flatten that for the viewmodel?  If there are many of these things then Clemens suggestion to build geometries into just one drawing or brush is likely to be more performant. Not awfully difficult once you take a look at how that stuff works AND you could freeze a geometry based drawing  so you can build it on a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must modify your `ItemsView` to support handling of a collection of `Rect` instead of a single `Rect`:

**ItemsView.cs**

```cs
public class ItemsView : Control
{
  public Item DataSource
  {
    get => (Item)GetValue(DataSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "DataSource",
    typeof(Item),
    typeof(ItemsView),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(Item), OnDataSourceChanged));

  private Panel ItemsHost { get; set; }
  private Dictionary<Rect, int> ContainerIndexTable { get; }
 
  static ItemsView() 
    => DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ItemsView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ItemsView)));

  public ItemsView() 
    => this.ContainerIndexTable = new Dictionary<Rect, int>();

  private static void OnDataSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    var this_ = d as ItemsView;
    this_.UnloadRectangles(e.OldValue as Item);
    this_.LoadRectangles(e.NewValue as Item);
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();      
    this.ItemsHost = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHost") as Panel;
    LoadRectangles(this.DataSource);
  }

  private void UnloadRectangles(Item item)
  {
    if (item is null
      || this.ItemsHost is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    foreach (Rect rectangleDefinition in item.ScaledRectangles)
    {
      if (this.ContainerIndexTable.TryGetValue(rectangleDefinition, out int containerIndex))
      {
        this.ItemsHost.Children.RemoveAt(containerIndex);
      }
    }
  }

  private void LoadRectangles(Item item)
  {
    if (item is null
      || this.ItemsHost is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    foreach (Rect rectangleDefinition in item.ScaledRectangles)
    {
      var container = new Rectangle()
      {
        Height = rectangleDefinition.Height,
        Width = rectangleDefinition.Width,
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(item.ItemColor)
      };

      Canvas.SetLeft(container, rectangleDefinition.Left);
      Canvas.SetTop(container, rectangleDefinition.Top);

      int containerIndex = this.ItemsHost.Children.Add(container);
      _ = this.ContainerIndexTable.TryAdd(rectangleDefinition, containerIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

**Gernic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:ItemsView">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ItemsView">
        <Canvas x:Name="PART_ItemsHost" />
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
      <local:ItemsView DataSource="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```